# Deleting multiple lines of terminal output using ruby

Tags: ruby, command-line, io

I would like to be able to output two lines to the terminal and then delete both of them. I know you can do one by doing something like

```
print "\b"*whatever
```

but I would like to do something more like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].each do |item|
    # code to delete the previous two lines
    print item.to_s + "\nHello!"
end
```

The output would quickly go through all of the following

```
1
Hello!
2
Hello!
3
Hello!
4
Hello!
5
Hello!
```

but by the end, the final iteration would be all you see.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, for simple things, if you can assume an ANSI-compatible terminal (usually a good bet), you can just directly output [ANSI codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). For instance,

```
 5.times do |item|
    print "\r" + ("\e[A\e[K"*3) if item > 0
    puts "#{item+1}\nHello!"
 end
```

Where `\r` moves the cursor to the start of the line, `\e[A` moves the cursor up one line, and `\e[K` clears from the cursor position to the end of the line.  If you don't need anything further down the screen, you can also just send `\e[J` once you have the cursor where you want; that clears all the way to the end of the screen.

For more sophisticated stuff, you could start by taking a look at [the Highline gem](http://highline.rubyforge.org/).